# Recuperating the option texte values in a multiple select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Sorry if my question was confusing. I have a view with a multi option select.

In the controller, those option values are coming back in the request as a comma separated string. I wonder if there's a smart way (since I'm not that good at CakePHP) to get the options text values as well as the option values.

```
<option value="[option value]">[option text value]</option>
```

Comment: Recuperate? I think you should use some other wording, at least _I_ have no clue what that means in the given, rather vague context. And even with a more understandable wording, your question really needs _more_ context, ie where exactly do want to to do what exactly, show an example of what you've tried so far, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you need but I am trying anyway.

The easiest solution i can imagine would be to just assign your option value text as your value.
Another solution would be to create an array in your controller containing the values of your select as array keys and the option text as array value
for example if your html looks like this.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Paypal</option>
    <option value="2">Sofort</option>
    <option value="3">Invoice</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller method:

```
$options = [
   1 => 'Paypal',
   2 => 'Sofort',
   3 => 'Invoice'
]
```

Now you can access the arrayValue coresponding to your option value and you get your text.